# Davening jacket that fits over tefillin

Tags: product-recommendation, clothing, tefilin

I try to wear a jacket while davening, which is usually not problematic during Minchah and Ma'ariv or Shabbat and Yom Tov. However, during Shacharit, it becomes somewhat difficult, as I try to wear my tefillah shel yad under my sleeve, rather than not wearing the left side of my jacket properly. Even though I wear fairly small tefillin (32mm), this is still difficult to accomplish with a normal jacket.

In short: is there a jacket available which is sized for wearing with tefillin on within the sleeve?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2tUK7o1H3c

Comment: Can you wear a bigger jacket? If I'm not mistaken, I think there are some sweatshirt or ski jackets that may have removable sleeves. Would this work, if I can locate a brand, or does it have to be a "black" button-down suit-type jacket? (BTW, I'm thinking of inventing a black hat with a front notch for the shel rosh. Seems tough to balance the hat on your head while wearing tefillin.)

Comment: @DanF, it wouldn't need to be black, but a sportscoat/suit jacket is what I had in mind. Bestt of luck with prototyping a tefillin hat BTW

Comment: @DanF like the kohanim did?

Comment: @Dude, I don't think that my ancestors who had the zechus to serve on Har haBayis wore fedoras, which is what I understood from DanF's comment.